# What's the new scope button style in the app store?

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, uisearchcontroller

I found a new style of scope button in the app store.
What keyword should I look for?

[New Style scope button!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmmAI.png)

Comment: May be when Thera is too many results, it add a filter.

Comment: What does "What keyword should I look for?" mean? What is the question?

Comment: @matt
I'm sorry. I'm not good at English.
As shown in the attached image, when searching in the app store, it appears to be using a new type of ScopeButton, not "UISortedControl".

I want to get a hint about this.

Comment: But "I want to get a hint" is not a question either. Are you asking how to _make_ something like this? It isn't some magical built-in thing. It's something you have to _program_. That's what programmers _do_. They make stuff. (And there is nothing called "UISortedControl" either.)

Comment: You're right. I'm sorry.
It's "UISegmentdControl" not "UISortedControl" ,when using scopeButtonTiles in UISearchbar